# Is it possible to use the Decomposed Theory of Planned Behavior to understand consumer behavior in relation to financial products?

Tags: consumer-psychology

The [Decomposed Theory of Planned Behavior](http://home.business.utah.edu/actme/7410/TaylorTodd.pdf), developed by Taylor and Todd,  is used to test consumer behavior regarding complex products. However, scholars use this theory only for technology related products.

Is it possible to use the DTPB for financial products as well?

Comment: Hi, Rabia. Welcome at Cogsci. I like you question, but do you have some references to the DTPB papers, or examples of the use of it. The more context you provide the better the answer will be. Moreover, people with similar questions may find it easier to understand your question.

Comment: There is [The use of a decomposed theory of planned behavior to study Internet banking in Taiwan](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a6ca/65c604ecfc4be9443b339c7ed519c70096ba.pdf)

Comment: Thankyou Robin Kramer and Chris Yes, extensive literature is available on DTPB but all studies are in context of information system (Gobi & Rad, 2015). However, Taylor and Todd, 1995 mentioned in their study that DTPB is for complex products and i think not only the technology products are complex or difficult for consumers to learn, financial products are also listed in the category of complex products